# Custom Command update CanExecute

Tags: wpf, command

I have to use this Command in a WPF application (i dont like it really but if i have to -> i have to ):
http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html

But the main problem I have here is that I don t want to have in nearly every line of my code a call to the

> RaiseCanExecuteChanged()

method. So what could I do to do that auto like RoutedUICommand does.

I have a lot of databindings and as example if Foo.FooProp != null Command can execute. But I want as less code as possible and so I would have to register events everywhere or update commands all over my application....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a form of `DelegateCommand` which invokes the delegates added to `CanExecuteChanged` everytime there is a change of possible consequence in the UI. This example uses [`CommandManager.RequerySuggested`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.requerysuggested.aspx).

```
public class AutoDelegateCommand : DelegateCommand, ICommand
{
    public AutoDelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : base(execute)
    {
    }        

    public AutoDelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        : base(execute, canExecute)
    {
    }

    event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```

I think I've seen an example like this before, perhaps in the MVVMLight toolkit?

Answer (score 4):

When I use a `DelegateCommand`, I just manually raise the `CanExecuteChanged` in the `PropertyChange` event whenever a property the command relies on changes.

Here's an example I did a few days ago where the `CanExecute` was based off the `IsLoading` and `IsValid` properties:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    this.PropertyChanged += MyViewModel_PropertyChanged;
}

void MyViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "IsLoading":
        case "IsValid":
            ((DelegateCommand)MyCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            break;
    }
}


public ICommand MyCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_myCommand == null)
            _myCommand = new DelegateCommand(Run, CanRun);

        return _myCommand;
    }
}

public bool CanRun()
{
    return this.IsValid && !IsLoading;
}
```

I find this keeps the logic easy to follow and maintain, and it only checks the `CanExecuteChanged()` method when the relevant properties change.

Comment: so glad i found this, its wayyyy better than specifically calling CanExecuteChanged all over the place for me